# How to create a custom WPF Window like this one?

Tags: wpf

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hehe would be nice to have a tool that could create Xaml and code behind from a Bitmap wouldn't it :) For one, it seems to be using WindowStyle="None"

Comment: Dear Meleak **Nothing is impossible these days**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following properties to your `Window` definition to get rid of the default style

```
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent"
```

I'm not sure the exact details of how they created their border but I'm guessing it has something to do with a Border which has a Transparent background, a CornerRadius, and perhaps a Blur Effect. It might actually be 2-3 borders (one black 1px one with a ~ 5 corner radius, a transparent one with the blur effect, and a third square one for around the content box)

Comment: Borders are default as all applications, only top **title, close minimize and maximize** piece is hide (maybe by API), I want to do this using WPF! However API unmanaged codes are welcome.

Comment: @Sadegh - The `AllowsTransparency` property gets rid of the border

Answer (score 1):

Using `Microsoft Expression Blend`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Expression Blend! can you provide more details?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Blend Hope this will be useful !